# Add a draggable window to a page using Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to create a Greasemonkey script that adds a draggable div to every web page. For some reason, the div isn't displaying at all. What might be the reason for this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Draggable box demo
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      *://www.*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js
// ==/UserScript==
//alert("Hi!");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).append("<div id='dragZone'><div class='draggable'>Drag here!<input type = 'text'></input></div>");
    $('#dragZone').css('position', 'absolute');
    var a = 3;
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
    });
    $('#dragZone div').mousedown(function() {
        $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
        $(this).css("z-index", a++);
    });
});
```

Comment: There's another script that does this: https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47608 I could use this script's source code, and this would be a reasonably good workaround.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've noticed that the script below only works on a few websites (such as Stackoverflow.com). Did you get it to work properly on other websites (such as google.com and jsfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely wrong on the first go - the issue is the use of `$(document).append`. You cannot append directly to the document, you can only append to a node.

So Either

```
$(document.body).append()
```

or

```
$('body').append()
```

[Here's the fiddle for proof.](http://jsfiddle.net/MPZXQ/)

It's probably the lack of the @require, maybe your greasemonkey is out of date?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://*/*
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==
jQuery(function($){
    var _highest = 0;   

    $("div").each(function() {
        var _current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
        if(_current > _highest) {
            _highest = _current + 1;
        }
    });
    $('body').append('<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;z-index:'+_highest+';left:100px;background:#ecebeb;border:1px solid #333;border-radius:5px;height:50px;width:300px;"> Hello, This is an addon div from Greasemonkey. </div>');
});
​
```

Boilerplate template. Should work fine OOB.

Comment: Which web page did you test it on, and which browser are you using? I'm using Google Chrome (which supports Greasemonkey scripts, like Firefox.)

Comment: Also, did you change anything besides the error that you mentioned in this post?

Comment: That was the only change I made. I use tampermonkey.

Comment: Which web page did you run the userscript on? I'm not sure if it works on all pages.

Comment: Surprisingly, this only works on some web pages, excluding http://www.google.com. It needs to be modified so that it will appear on top of all other elements in the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21364/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-ohgodwhy)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a working userscript that adds a draggable div to every page. Here is the source code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Div on top
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      https://*/*
// @match      http://*/*
// @match      *.com*
// @match      *.net*
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==
jQuery(function($){
    var _highest = 0;   

    $("div").each(function() {
        var _current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
        if(_current > _highest) {
            _highest = _current + 1;
        }
    });
    $('body').append('<div id = "draggableDiv" class = "ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute;top:'+GM_getValue("top")+'px;z-index:'+_highest+';left:'+GM_getValue("left")+'px;background:#ecebeb;border:1px solid #333;border-radius:5px;height:50px;width:300px;"> Hello, This is an addon div from Greasemonkey. <input type = "text" value = "type something here"></input> </div>');
    $( "#draggableDiv" ).draggable();
    $('#draggableDiv').mouseup(function() {
        //alert('Set the x and y values using GM_getValue.');
        var divOffset = $("#draggableDiv").offset();
        var left = divOffset.left;
        var top = divOffset.top;
        GM_setValue("left", left);
        GM_setValue("top", top);
        //alert("Set left to " + left + " and top to " + top);
    });
});
```