# Place a sidebar on every page using a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script that will place a navigational sidebar on every web page that it is loads on, but I still don't know of a way to do this without covering up some of the content on each page. Is there any way to place a `div` at the side of each page that is loaded, without covering up any of the page's content?

Comment: Someone found a way to do this for Chrome extensions, and it might work for Greasemonkey scripts as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100540/chrome-extension-inject-sidebar-into-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question you linked's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101251/331508) placed an offset on the whole page, while demonstrating a top bar, not a side bar.  That technique is lousy for a right-sidebar because it chops off (hides) a slice of the left side of the page.

A better technique if you want to go that route (which I don't recommend), is to adjust the page width.  Here's one way in **a complete Greasemonkey script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Sidebar on page
// @include  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722302/*
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var sidebarWidth    = "100px";

$("html").css ( {
    position:   "relative",
    width:      "calc(100% - " + sidebarWidth + ")"
} );

$("body").append ( '                                                \
    <div id="gmRightSideBar">                                       \
        <ul>                                                        \
            <li><a href="http://dailypuppy.com/">Link 1</a></li>    \
            <li><a href="http://puppyfind.com/">Link 2</a></li>     \
        </ul>                                                       \
    </div>                                                          \
' );

GM_addStyle ( "                                                     \
    #gmRightSideBar {                                               \
        position:               fixed;                              \
        top:                    0;                                  \
        right:                  0;                                  \
        margin:                 1ex;                                \
        padding:                1em;                                \
        background:             orange;                             \
        width:                  calc(" + sidebarWidth + " - 2ex)    \
    }                                                               \
    #gmRightSideBar ul {                                            \
        margin:                 0ex;                                \
    }                                                               \
    #gmRightSideBar a {                                             \
        color:                  blue;                               \
    }                                                               \
" );
```

Use CSS to position and style everything, and use jQuery to simplify the code and make it more robust/portable.

---

---

But, rather than compressing or shifting the page, and potentially busting its layout, **go ahead and cover up some of the right-side content.**  [This is almost always wasted space that usually gets ignored](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) (and several other links and studies).

If your sidebar remains mostly invisible, when not hovered over, and has a handy keyboard shortcut to toggle its visibility, then it will be no trouble at all that it sometimes partially obscures right-side content.  I've been using this technique for years and it works well.

**A complete Greasemonkey script** to do that is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add a Sidebar to a page with auto fade and keyboard shortcut
// @include  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722302/*
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

$("body").append ( '                                                \
    <div id="gmRightSideBar">                                       \
        <p>F9 toggles visibility</p>                                \
        <ul>                                                        \
            <li><a href="http://dailypuppy.com/">Link 1</a></li>    \
            <li><a href="http://puppyfind.com/">Link 2</a></li>     \
        </ul>                                                       \
    </div>                                                          \
' );

//-- Fade panel when not in use
var kbShortcutFired = false;
var rightSideBar    = $('#gmRightSideBar');
rightSideBar.hover (
    function () {
        $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (50,  1  );
        kbShortcutFired = false;
    },
    function () {
        if ( ! kbShortcutFired ) {
            $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (900, 0.1);
        }
        kbShortcutFired = false;
    }
);
rightSideBar.fadeTo (2900, 0.1);

//-- Keyboard shortcut to show/hide our sidebar
$(window).keydown (keyboardShortcutHandler);

function keyboardShortcutHandler (zEvent) {
    //--- On F9, Toggle our panel's visibility
    if (zEvent.which == 120) {  // F9
        kbShortcutFired = true;

        if (rightSideBar.is (":visible") ) {
            rightSideBar.stop (true, false).hide ();
        }
        else {
            //-- Reappear opaque to start
            rightSideBar.stop (true, false).show ();
            rightSideBar.fadeTo (0, 1);
            rightSideBar.fadeTo (2900, 0.1);
        }

        zEvent.preventDefault ();
        zEvent.stopPropagation ();
        return false;
    }
}

GM_addStyle ( "                                                     \
    #gmRightSideBar {                                               \
        position:               fixed;                              \
        top:                    0;                                  \
        right:                  0;                                  \
        margin:                 1ex;                                \
        padding:                1em;                                \
        background:             orange;                             \
        width:                  100px;                              \
        z-index:                6666;                               \
        opacity:                0.9;                                \
    }                                                               \
    #gmRightSideBar p {                                             \
        font-size:              80%;                                \
    }                                                               \
    #gmRightSideBar ul {                                            \
        margin:                 0ex;                                \
    }                                                               \
    #gmRightSideBar a {                                             \
        color:                  blue;                               \
    }                                                               \
" );
```

Comment: The second script works well, but it covers up some of the user interface elements at the top of the page on youtube.com. Would it be possible to make the sidebar draggable (in order to work around this problem)?

Comment: Yes, you can make it draggable; didn't you have [a question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13946047/331508) already?  Probably easier just to set the top a little lower and/or get used to hitting `F9` but, for draggable, just `@require` jQuery-UI and call `rightSideBar.draggable()` to start.

Comment: Interestingly, I noticed that the `F9` shortcut doesn't work when the mouse is hovering over the sidebar. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Huh, That's never come up before (note that my panels also have a close button, so hovering while using the shortcut is unlikely).  Anyway, the revised code fixes the problem.  (Hiding the div triggered de-hover.)